# data overlapped in timeline highchart while exporting

Tags: highcharts, export, timeline

How can we handle large data in Timeline Highcharts while exporting?
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeCJV.png

As shown in the attached image, call-out boxes for the timeline should not be overlapping with one another.

Comment: Hi @aishwarya aggarwal, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? You can use this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sfqxe8c7/ to start.

Comment: your image link not work